# Elementary Proof of Erdos for prime number theorem.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Where can I find a good proof that has a good and elementary explanation?
I've googled it, but what I found is not exact and complete.
I want a complete proof without any referencing.

Comment: I recall an exposition of this proof  in American Mathematical Monthly, circa 1971$\pm 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the original paper.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063042/

You can get a PDF of the scans of the journal pages.